# adding yet another domain to multi-site but this time symlink not working

Tags: multi-sites

Have no idea what's going on here. I'm trying to add another new domain to my multi-site but keeps directing to apache test page - not install.php.

Have many subdomains installed now and one new domain added to root one but this next one is giving me problems for some reason. Everything has been done same way. Set up in server to point to IP; separate database created; name of domain in sites folder created with default.settings.php copied to it as settings.php and chmod 644 then a symlink from the /var/www/html folder to the sites one but as I say just keep getting apache test page. Not found if try going to install.php. This is happened to me before but don't have a thorough understanding why...i am suspecting has something to do with database- not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your database. At this point you have probably a problem completely unrelated to Drupal. Instead your Apache is not aware of your Drupal installation.

Here is a list of things you should check:

- Is that domain we're talking about pointing to your server (or do you see the test page of a different one): compare IP by `ping yourserver.com`

  - If it's a "testdomain" you might want to add an entry to `/etc/hosts`
- Is your virtual host configured correctly?

  - Did you set a `ServerName` or a `ServerAlias`
  - If you were setting up a new VHost, did you enable it (`sudo a2ensite yourhost` for instance)
  - Did you restart Apache/reload configuration after doing this (`sudo service apache2 reload`)?
  - Did you configure your VHost/your root directory to follow symlinks?
  - Have you set `NameVirtualHosts`?
- Are your symlinks pointing to the right folder?

  - Do you get the contents of your settings.php by typing `cat /var/www/html/sites/symlink/settings.php` in a terminal or an error?

As an example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName yourdomain.com
  ServerAlias sub1.yourdomain.com sub2.yourdomain.com # etc ...
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  <Directory /var/www/html>
    AllowOverride All
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks Multiviews
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Again, it's most probably not Drupal related. It would be if you'd see a different one of your multisites or Drupal complaining about something but since you got the Apache test page you might want to ask on a different board (serverfault) and provide some more information (OS, directory structure, current host configuration and so on) if my checklist didn't help you.

Answer (score -2):

I just worked it out but thank yu for above important list of reminders.

Was symlinking to sites folder instead of drupal folder- knew it was something simple.

So logical and yet totally passed over my head ;o

Comment: If you accidentally created a second account, you can use the Contact Us link in the footer to request the accounts be merged.

Comment: its ok i don't mind haha

Comment: trying to be polite when so much trouble they went to help answer question but couldn't log in cause fb de activated account - i hate the red tape of forums but love the help! ;)